# Build tensorflow for Raspberry Pi

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, bazel, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to build tensorflow from source for the raspberry pi using the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi) but it fails really early in the build process.

I'm trying to build tag `v2.0.0`.

I'm running the following on `Ubuntu 18.04.3`:

```
CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.4" tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON3 tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
```

I fails with:

```
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: 4 targets (3 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
ERROR: /home/fgervais/personal/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fgervais/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/local_config_arm_compiler/BUILD:32:1: @local_config_arm_compiler//:cc-compiler-local: missing value for mandatory attribute 'toolchain_config' in 'cc_toolchain' rule
ERROR: /home/fgervais/personal/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fgervais/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/local_config_arm_compiler/BUILD:45:1: @local_config_arm_compiler//:cc-compiler-armeabi: missing value for mandatory attribute 'toolchain_config' in 'cc_toolchain' rule
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'nsync' which is a tf_http_archive (rule definition at /workspace/third_party/repo.bzl:124:19):
 - /workspace/tensorflow/workspace.bzl:444:5
 - /workspace/WORKSPACE:19:1
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'arm_compiler' which is a tf_http_archive (rule definition at /workspace/third_party/repo.bzl:124:19):
 - /workspace/tensorflow/workspace.bzl:180:5
 - /workspace/WORKSPACE:19:1
ERROR: /home/fgervais/personal/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fgervais/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/local_config_arm_compiler/BUILD:32:1: Target '@local_config_arm_compiler//:empty' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '@local_config_arm_compiler//:cc-compiler-local'
ERROR: /home/fgervais/personal/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fgervais/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/local_config_arm_compiler/BUILD:7:1: Target '@local_config_arm_compiler//:cc-compiler-armeabi' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '@local_config_arm_compiler//:toolchain'
ERROR: /home/fgervais/personal/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fgervais/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/local_config_arm_compiler/BUILD:7:1: Target '@local_config_arm_compiler//:cc-compiler-local' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '@local_config_arm_compiler//:toolchain'
ERROR: /workspace/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/BUILD:70:1: every rule of type cc_binary implicitly depends upon the target '@local_config_arm_compiler//:toolchain', but this target could not be found because of: Target '@local_config_arm_compiler//:toolchain' contains an error and its package is in error
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.914s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (54 packages loaded, 82 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (54 packages loaded, 82 targets configured)
```

Building through docker should be quite reproducible, I'm not sure what could be wrong on my end that would make it fail.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Ok well `v2.1.0-rc0` does work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but even though the build is made through a repeatable docker environment and that tag `v2.0.0` is a stable tensorflow version, it seems like the build for the raspberry pi is broken.

All I can say is that it is fixed in version `v2.1.0-rc0` and `v2.1.0-rc1`.

Using the following command on the two tags:

```
CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.4"     tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON3     tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
```

I successfully generated those wheels:

```
tensorflow-2.1.0rc0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
tensorflow-2.1.0rc1-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```